# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}e^{in}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

Analyze the convergence of the serie $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}e^{in}$ .

I have this:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}e^{in}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\cos(n)+i \sin(n)=\cos(1)+\cos(2)+....=e^{\frac{i(n-1)}{2}} \frac{\sin(n/2)}{\sin(1/2)} .$$

What do I do now?

Comment: Use the fact that $\lim_{n \to \infty} e^{in} \neq 0$ and the fact that for any convergent series $\sum_{n} a_n$ we must have that $\lim_n a_n = 0$.

Comment: Therefore $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}e^{in}$ diverges

Comment: And that would be enough for the solution, right? @MustafaSaid

Comment: yes, and for a complete solution make sure you rigorously prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} e^{in} \neq 0$.

Comment: Thank you! @MustafaSaid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the fact, for a convergent series,  $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty}a_n=0$.

Also notice that, real or complex, $e^{in} \neq 0$.

Therefore, the series does not converge, because the individual terms do not tend towards zero.

---

Note, the series does not tend to $+\infty$, that is a common assumption to make when finding out that a series does not converge.

All this says, is that the series does not converge to a single value.